# PHP foreach set row name as new variable

Tags: php, mysql

My Php function loops trough the mysql table and for each row it sets the row name as $var and the row value to $val.

```
foreach($row as $var => $val) {...
```

Now I want to set the received rowname ($var) as a new variable.

This example is not right but to explain my thoughts ; $name$var = $val

If $var would be = rowname1 
then the new variable would be $rowname1 = value1

Any ideas how to achieve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) to do that:

```
foreach(...) {
    $$var = $val;
}
```

But cleaner would be to use an array:

```
foreach(...) {
    $var_names[] = array($var => $val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$array = array(
'go' => 'something1',
'go2' => 'something2',
'go3' => 'something3',
'go4' => 'something4',
'go5' => 'something5',
);

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
    ${$key} = $val;
}

print $go;

?>
```

**[`EXAMPLE`](http://codepad.org/SngI2eES)**

or you could use the `$$` way explained here:
[`Read more about Variable Variables...`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like `${$var} = $val`. Curly brackets are there just for convenience and readability. `$$var = $val` should also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can create variables with dynamic names on the fly using strings! This is supported in the [documentation provided here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

A quick example:

```
// This now holds the string hello
$variableName = 'hello';

// This creates the variable 'hello' and contains the value test
$$variableName = "test";
echo $hello;
```

With the above example complete you will be able to create a variable name with the key + value strings as follows:

```
$count = 1;
foreach($row as $var => $val)
{
    $varName = $var.$count;
    $$varName = $val;
    $count++;
}
```

This will create column_name1, column_name2 etc.

I feel the need to add a little discretion as this is not common or best practice. The best way to handle this information would be to take the $key => $val pair and store it into a separate variable or parse through them. By doing this you are basically throwing away all of the ease of use that is using arrays.

Also, side note:

You can also dynamically call on methods this way.

```
function test()
{
    echo "test yar";
}

$method = "test";
$method();
```